# Returning a list using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to return list. Any suggestion would be highly appreciable. Thanks in Advance.

It throws this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<HTentityFramework.tblFlower>` to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<HTentityFramework.testDomain>`

Code is:

```
public class GetFlowers
{
   public IList<testDomain> getFlowerList()
   {
      TestContainer ctx = new TestContainer();
      return ctx.tblFlowers.ToList();
   }
}

public class testDomain
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It Throws error as Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HTentityFramework.tblFlower>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HTentityFramework.testDomain>'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is pretty clear - just **read it!**

The type you're returning from `getFlowerList` is `IList<testDomain>` - yet you're selecting from an EF object set that's called `tblFlowers`.

The error clearly says that this is an `IList<tblFlower>` - a list of `tblFlower` objects.

Your code cannot just convert a list of `tblFlowers` to a list of `testDomain` - that's the whole point.

You need to either provide a conversion yourself, or you need to return a `IList<tblFlower>` from your method:

```
public IList<tblFlower> getFlowerList()   <==== return an IList<tblFlower> here!!
{
    TestContainer ctx = new TestContainer();
    return ctx.tblFlowers.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solving the issue. But dont we use TestDomain classes in Ilist?

Comment: @Usham: if you select from `tblFlowers`, then you get back a list of `tblFlower` objects - so you need to return those ..... if you want to "hide" that fact and return some other type instead - it's **up to you** to provide some kind of a conversion/mapping from the real, actual type returned by EF (`tblFlower`) to some **other datatype** that you might have defined. Again: your job, and it needs to be clear, explicit - no magic in .NET can do this for you